# how do c compilers for android work.

Tags: android, c, compiler-construction

There are several applications for android such as "C4droid" that can compile C code, i want to know how android compiles C code

To run python android uses SL4A, what is the equivalent for C code.

Comment: Do you mean compile or run? They make no difference to python but they do to C.

Comment: I know that python is not a compiled language and i should of said that in the question, but i did include it as an example of how android can run a programing language.

Comment: Android is based on linux, so that's easy to run 'compiled C code' on it. And that should be native.

Comment: @neohope i know that android can run 'compiled C code' i am asking how does android compile it, not how it runs code that was compiled on a desktop computer.

Comment: There's plenty of technical information how C4droid works at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc&hl=en - do you have a specific question? As such, this question is too open-ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Provides C/C++ SDK known as ["Android NDK"](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) which communicate with the hardware.Upon that harware Android OS is installed followed by native Application.

Application which require real time compilation are build on Android NDK.